# How can I break the loop before printing 506?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I stop the program below the criteria? See the example below -  I don't want 506 in the print. Please help!

```
# break Statement

mySum = 0
for i in range(0, 1000, 2):
    mySum += i
    print(mySum)
    if mySum >= 500:
        break
print(mySum)  

**Output:**
0
2
6
12
20
30
42
56
72
90
110
132
156
182
210
240
272
306
342
380
420
462
506
506
```

Comment: So put the `if` statement **before** the `print()`?

Comment: Not that your question is clear. You now have 506 printed twice. Did you not want `mySum` to end up at 506 (and so see it printed *once*?

Answer (score 1):

Simply test for your `break` condition **before** printing:

```
for i in range(0, 1000, 2):
    mySum += i
    if mySum >= 500:
        break
    print(mySum)
```

So now the loop will end the moment you reach 506, but it won't be printed in the loop.

If you wanted `mySum` to be lower or equal to 500, you also need to alter your test too, so change it to `mySum <= 500` instead. You'll end up with `mySum` set to `462` after the loop, and the last value printed would be 420.